# Как сделать выбранным только один CheckBox в списке RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть `RecyclerView`, с кастомным row. В каждом row есть `CheckBox`.

**Задача:** нужно сделать так, чтобы в один момент времени был выбран только один `CheckBox`.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Код Адаптера:

```
//массив, размер которого равен кол-ву строчек, если значение true - то на этой строчке CheckBox.set(true) etc.
private boolean[] checked;
private int previous_number = -2;
private static CheckBox lastChecked = null;
...
  public FriendsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FriendDataClass> contacts) {    
        checked = new boolean[contacts.size()];
        ...
    }
...
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {       
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {       

           holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

             if (previous_number == -2){
                  //данное условие срабатывает, когда мы первый раз нажимаем на любой элемент
               holder.choice_cb.setChecked(true);
               checked[position] = true;
               previous_number = position;
               lastChecked = holder.choice_cb;
               notifyDataSetChanged();
               Log.d("***", "сработало 1 условие");
           } else {
                   //данное условие срабатывает, если мы уже нажимали на какой-либо элемент
               if (checked[position]){
                   // в данное условие мы заходим, если нажали на элемент, который уже выбрал (стоит true)
                   holder.choice_cb.setChecked(false);
                   checked[position] = false;
                   lastChecked = null;
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                   Log.d("***", "сработало 2 условие");
               } else {
                   // в данное условие мы заходим, если нажали на элемент, который еще не выбран (стоит false)
                   holder.choice_cb.setChecked(true);
                   checked[position] = true;

                   if (lastChecked != null){
                       lastChecked.setChecked(false);
                       notifyItemChanged(previous_number);
                       Log.d("***", "зашли в проверку в 3 условии");
                   }
                   lastChecked = holder.choice_cb;
                   previous_number = position;
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                   Log.d("***", "сработало 3 условие");

               }
           }



        });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все гораздо проще, вам не нужен массив отмеченных чекбоксов и его прошлые позиции, ведь у вас в каждый момент времени может быть только один (или ни одного) выбранного чекбокса. Предлагаю такой адаптер (адаптер принимает в качестве данных массив строк `items`, но вы без труда сможете исправить его под свой тип данных):

```
public class SingleChoiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SingleChoiceAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> items;
    int checkedPosition = -1;

    public SingleChoiceAdapter (ArrayList<String> items){
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        ItemHolder holder = new ItemHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.text.setText(items.get(position));
        // Устанавливаем отметку на чекбоксе, позиция которого равна отмеченной
        // выражение будет true только при совпадении текущей позиции
        // и отмеченной - этот чекбокс выделится
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(position == checkedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void setCheckedPosition (int position){
        checkedPosition = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getChecedPosition (){
        return checkedPosition;
    }

    class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView text;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // при нажатии на элемент проверяем отмечен ли чекбокс в данной позиции
                // если нет, то запоминаем позицию для отметки
                // если отмечен, то сбрасываем отметку (ставим -1)
                checkedPosition = checkBox.isChecked() ? -1: getAdapterPosition();
                // обновляем список, чтобы убрать прошлую! отметку и показать новую
                notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
}
```

методом `setCheckedPosition()` вы можете принудительно установить нужный чекбокс (или передать -1, чтобы сбросить все), а методом `getCheckedPosition()` получить от адаптера отмеченный (или -1, если не выбран ни один).

Вы можете доработать адаптер и прокинуть колбэк для своевременной реакции на изменения чекбоксов вне адаптера, если вам это требуется.

**UPD**
Немного изменил логику, чтобы клик был на всем айтеме, а не только на чекбоксе. Для чекбокса в разметке нужно поставить свойство `android:clickable="false"`, чтобы он не перехватывал фокус на клик по айтему.

Ссылка на [проект в GitHub](https://github.com/pavlofff/RecyclerViewSingleChoice)

PS: колбэк `OnCheckedChangeListener` назначенный чекбоксу, при вызове `notifyDataSetChanged()` выкидывает экзепшен с сообщением *Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling*, поэтому от него пришлось отказаться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, массив отмеченных чекбоксов и его прошлые позиции нужны были в предыдущей версии, я его забыл убрать)

Comment: По поводу колбэка для `OnCheckedChangeListener ` я читал, поэтому сразу отказался от этого и решил повесить `lisntear` на `holder` в `onBindViewHolder`. 
А можно ли повесить `listnear`на всю строчку, а не только на `CheckBox` ? Что-то я совсем запутался..

Comment: Точнее вопрос не в том, как повесить `listnear` на всю строчку, а как убрать сделать "uncheck" предыдущего `CheckBox`, если пользователь нажал на новый..

Comment: @Denis422 смотрите **UPD** в ответе. Вам не нужно ничего специально убирать с прошлого чекбокса, при обновлении списка он сам снимет отметку. Добавил комментарии в код, как это все работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь разобрался. А я пытался в ручную убирать отметку с предыдущего чекбокса